# How would a shrink ray work without actually “shrinking” a living being?

Tags: technology, super-powers, medical

I’m trying to create a “shrink ray” in a Star Wars-esque technological level world. Yet I don’t want it to be rubber Clarketech science. I want it to be almost like virtual; leaning towards shrinking someone but it being up to interpretation of whether they are actually shrunken down. I imagine it would be used for medical purposes like a super-advanced doctor check-up. How could this “shrink ray” work?

Comment: What, exactly, does "it being up to interpretation of whether they are actually shrunken down" mean? Someone gets shrunk, they enter someone else's ear to perform delicate surgery... but you want a solution that leaves the reader wondering if that person really was shrunk down? Why doesn't "a miniature robot of me with a brain interface to control it" not solve your problem?

Comment: That’s a good first start.

Comment: VTC Needs more details. Asking vague questions believing you'll get a larger array of answers to choose from goes against the fundamental premise of Stack Exchange. Idea-generating questions are a tough sell to begin with. Please clearly explain your problem, why you can't overcome it, your specific goals and/or expectations for the answer, and any limitations/conditions/restrictions you may have. (See [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask].)

Comment: I know. I just don’t know exactly what I’m looking for. It’s like this. Teleportation is transfer from one place to another instantaneously. Let’s say a society called teleportation a really advanced holo-conference where you think you are in a different place. We have hoverboards but they aren’t like the ones in Back to the Future.

Comment: We're not a site for brainstorming or idea-generation. Please follow site policy and try to ask specific answerable questions rather than fish for ideas. If you don't know what you want then *any* answer is equally valid, so make something up and go with that.

Comment: No. I said what I wanted. A technology that operates similar to what it’s name is but isn’t quite what it seems. 

Like the hoverboard in the real world. It really doesn’t hover but it does provide transportation.

Comment: *"I just don't know exactly what I'm looking for"* It's not our job to tell you how technology in your world works. If it's a ray that shrinks people or a virtual leaning whatever, that's not something we can help you with. You need to figure out what tech exists in your world, and what it does. If you want cars made from rocks, if you want shrinking spaceships, if you want everything to be solved by the power of friendship, these are decisions you need to make for yourself. Then ask us for help resolving specific issues you are having, not making things up.

Comment: Well I was looking for some concept that may be esoteric and that I didn’t think of.

Comment: We're not an concept generation site, or a brainstorming site, open ended questions are not permitted here. When you have come up with the concept you're going with, we'll be happy to help you solve any specific problems you have with it. But since you can choose whatever concept you want such a question would be too broad, and to opinion based to be allowed here.

Comment: i agree that it is impossible.to provide a quality answer to this question. you need to listen to feedback and rework it or give up on getting valuable answers. you barely made the effort to make us understand what you are looking for

Comment: Based on the criteria, I assume this shrink-ray actually just enlarges the rest of the universe - giving the perception that the targeted object has shrunk by comparison.

Comment: While sphennings can come off as harsh, he's right. We're here mainly to help you with fleshing out some details of what you want. If you don't know what you want, it becomes much harder to help. You're asking for something that is by your definition unclear and broad, having to simultaneously do and not do what it's meant to. It'd be best for you to take a step back in the process and understand what is the problem you need to solve and what kind of solution you'd like. For example: you don't have a good grasp on what your technology is useful for or what it's meant to achieve.

Comment: Also do remember that, despite your criticism and my own preferences for some level of realism in what I create, it's not always a bad thing not to explain how something works, especially if you actually cannot explain and must resort to complicated technobabble that sounds complicated but actually says nothing. Leaving things almost or completely unexplained is also great if you deliberately want your creation to be mysterious, ominous or simply up to interpretation (the moment anyone gives a proper explanation on how your ray "shrinks" someone, it's no longer up to interpretation).

Comment: Consider: (a) [Why asking for details isn't always a good idea](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8290/40609) and (b) [Advice concerning questions asking HOW to implement a technological procedure or device](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8273/40609).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called a mind scrambler.

We have had historical cases of people thinking they're made out of glass despite the people physically proving every day just by walking around that they aren't made of glass. Yours is fairly mundane.

SO just have a mind scrambler that makes people think they have shrunk, actual reality will not sway them from their conviction.

Comment: If we're going the way of mind-alteration, it's probably good to look at the [syndrom of Alice in Wonderland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_in_Wonderland_syndrome).

Comment: @Tortliena That's a great reference! Unfortunately, the OP hasn't told us if the shrunken person actually needs to act that way. In other words, does the person enter someone's ear canal or not? Are we dealing with a "reality" that a shrunken person could achieve whether it was the person who shrank, the "patient" (in my example) who was enlarged, or a dimensional shift that allowed the microsurgery without any change at all? We're all focusing on the dubious-if-they-really-shrank part and not getting clarification on the did-the-effects-of-shrinking-actually-happen part.